# Não aparece todos os atributos adicionais no android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, interface, intellij

Grande comunidade, estou iniciando agora no Android Studio e de cara já me deparei com um "problema" que não consegui resolver, preciso da ajuda dos senhores.

Preciso vincular uma função à um botão, porém, desde que instalei, não aparece todos os atributos de um item selecionado via interface, e eu não consegui achar nada que voltasse a aparecer todos os atributos.

Segue o print
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, procure desenvolver seus layouts pelo xml.... Você pode fazer isso selecionando a aba Text ao invés de Design.... Lá em baixo.... Desenvolver desta maneira é muito mais fácil e você aprende melhor a manipular seus layouts

Comment: Lá no xml do botão adicione o método ``android:onClick="click"``

Comment: Certo, obrigado pela dica @Andréalas!

E o método deu certo, vlw!

Comment: De nada amigo.... faz um favor pra mim.... dá um up no meu comentário pra mim ganhar um pouquinho de reputação....